# QGIS displays satellite data very blurry when ArcGIS Pro looks clear?

Tags: qgis, imagery, satellite

I am looking at a WorldView 3 image in QGIS (right in image) and in ArcGIS Pro (left) and there is a huge difference in quality. QGIS looks so blurry/a lower resolution.

Any idea what's happening?

[image: c]

Comment: Note: this is 8-bit data

Comment: Some settings are different between both images, since what in the Arc-image is shadows, is displayed white in QGIS. Make sure your settings are as similar as possible.

Comment: Yeah I think I got them as similar as I can. Just very strange. Hopefully when I get the 16bit data it will look good in both since not everyone I work with has access to arcmap

Answer (score 4):

It looks like different images to me... On the right side, there is much less green a much more "something" that looks like water. I think that image was acquired with different conditions (during floods?) Images from same sensor can substantially differ in quality, based on weather, time of day, angle of camera and so on... As another one sugestet, try to replicate display settings as much as possible, but bear in mind, that won't help if two images differ to much in the radiometric properties. Then you have to set display settings that fits to current image. That can involve some trials and errors. And of course, if that image is of poor quality, you can try but, you won't be able to get same results as from good image. Bad image is bad image, no matter how many episodes of CSI Las Vegas you have watched

Comment: it's the exact same image I just dragged it into QGIS and Arcmap. Which is why I am so confused

Comment: @Emtomp Maybe some sample of that image will help...

Answer (score 1):

Change the rendering option for zoomed in and zoomed out to something else than nearest neighbour.  That should help with the fuzziness.  Make sure the SAME 3 band are shown in RGB mode. Change in min and max for each bands.